# Create a Border with Different Edges / Sides

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

[image]

How to create a **Border** with different edges. Do not have to be the exact the same. Just want to know how to set four different **styles** to border.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant do it with border but you can create a content control with same style some thing like.

```
<Style x:Key="DiffBorderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Rectangle 
                        Fill="Black" Width="1" 
                        Grid.RowSpan="3"/>

                        <Rectangle 
                        Fill="Blue" Width="1" 
                        Grid.Column="2"
                        Grid.RowSpan="3"/>

                        <Rectangle 
                        Fill="Red" Height="1" 
                        Grid.ColumnSpan="3"/>

                        <Rectangle 
                        Fill="Black"  Height="1" 
                        Grid.Row="2"
                        Grid.ColumnSpan="3"/>

                        <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"/>
                    </Grid>


                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

You can stylized each rectangle in style and also you can use Line in place of rectangle.

Hope it helps..

Comment: Thank you for ur answer, but I need the style for border for some reasons.

Comment: @dongx You can not change the border style as the way you want. But why you need to work only with border?

Answer (score 5):

I don't think there is a way to control border style of each side. You can however put 4 borders on top of each other (or within each other) each having corresponding side with desired style and other sides with width 0

Comment: Thanks, I thought about this by setting the thickness to be 0, but I have not tried yet. Just wonder is there any other way to do this, but  still thank you so much!

Comment: @dongx I don't think there is any other way, if you break any of the third party controls like telerik or devexpress in blend, this is how they do it. Usually border within border, a bit ugly but does the trick. Mark this as an answer if you are satisfied.